# How to configure a vuejs app with an external file

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, configuration, .env

so i've been trying to `configure my vuejs app (i.e backend_url, some key etc..)`, i've tried to use `.env files like in nodejs servers`, but `browsers don't support .env configuration` like nodejs platform does.

Currently i'm using a `json file` in which i put the configuration properties, then read them inside the app, this solution works for now, but the question is `won't we need to rebuild the app when we change the json file??` i.e if we change some property or add a new one, does that mean i have to build again??

If there's any better approach to properly configure vuejs apps please tell, i'll  be so grateful.

Comment: Looks like you can [use .env files with Vue](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#using-env-variables-in-client-side-code).

Comment: what does "properly" mean? A .env file is useful for configuring back-end stuff (so, not vue) or build time stuff ... so, yes, if you change the .env file, you'd rebuild and redeploy ... other config can be done through AJAX ... other than configuring a back-end url of course ... that, you can configure in your app, and store in localstorage or some other client side storage

Comment: Thank you @Andy for your great reply, i have tried to use .env files, but it didn't work as i said as browsers don't support such configuration as i have read, i'll go across the blog you provided again to see if i did something wrong.

Comment: Thank you indeed @JaromandaX, seems like even the frontend's configuration is done in backend, i think i'll add a route to get configuration from backend when the frontend starts running

Answer (score 0):

****Step 1:** Create the configuration file**
Create a new JSON file (e.g., config.json) that contains the configuration settings you want to use in your Vue.js app:

```js
     {
      "apiBaseUrl": "https://api.example.com",
      "apiKey": "your_api_key_here",
      "enableFeatureX": true,
      "maxItemsPerPage": 10
     }
```

****Step 2:** Import the configuration file in your Vue app**

In your Vue app's entry point (e.g., main.js), import the configuration file using an HTTP request or a build tool like Webpack.

Example using Axios (ensure you have Axios installed):

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import axios from 'axios';

axios.get('/path/to/config.json')
  .then(response => {
    Vue.prototype.$config = response.data;
    new Vue({
      render: h => h(App),
    }).$mount('#app');
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error loading config:', error);
  });
```

****Step 3:** Use the configuration settings in your Vue components**

Now that you've loaded the configuration settings into Vue's prototype, you can access them in your Vue components using this.$config.

For example, in any of your Vue components:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <p>API Base URL: {{ $config.apiBaseUrl }}</p>
    <p>API Key: {{ $config.apiKey }}</p>
    <p v-if="$config.enableFeatureX">Feature X is enabled.</p>
    <p>Max Items Per Page: {{ $config.maxItemsPerPage }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    console.log('API Base URL:', this.$config.apiBaseUrl);
    console.log('API Key:', this.$config.apiKey);
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you [@Mohammad Hassan Rafay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15069684/mohammad-hassan-rafay) for your great answer, however, i am using <script setup> syntax, i don't know if using $config will allow me to access the configuration, i'll try it to make sure.